# Java 4 USb LibUsb.controlTransfer returns -9

Tags: java, libusb

new to low level usb pprogramming but I am trying to write two bytes to a USB port and into a device called an EASYDAQ switch (its essentially a serial to parrallel board), everything else appears OK i.e finds a device handle etc But when I try the transfer I get -9 as the result. I dont know how to proceed. Here is the code, its copied form usb4java and I also dont fully understand what all the command line args are doing either and i would be very grateful if anyone could enlighten me, many thanks in advance..

```
    public static void sendMessage(DeviceHandle handle, byte[] message)
    {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(message.length);
    buffer.put(message);
   // buffer.rewind();
    int transfered = LibUsb.controlTransfer(handle,
    (byte) (LibUsb.REQUEST_TYPE_CLASS | LibUsb.RECIPIENT_INTERFACE),
    (byte) 0x09, (short) 2, (short) 1, buffer, TIMEOUT);
    if (transfered < 0)
    throw new LibUsbException("Control transfer failed", transfered);
    if (transfered != message.length)
    throw new RuntimeException("Not all data was sent to device");
    }
```

one more final thing once I send this message and get the failing response I have to power cycle the device I am trying to communicate to otherwise I get a message it cant find my device.